# Pushing a Sine wave through a piece of geometry while it is translating/scaling/rotating

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, shader, trigonometry

This is the prelude/simple example to kickstart my bigger idea.

Question: How can we deform the cube's vertices using a sine wave while the cube is scaling, translating or rotating.

Note: Maybe there's some post processing effect I'm not aware of for this and therefore, animating vertices are not best suited for this.

Note 2: My final goal is to push music/audio through geometry/mesh so it has more of an effect like so:

[image]

Just to clarify I would like the effect of this image above and I would also like it to be animated and be a piece of 3d geometry not 2d rastered image.

but I fear adding this audio feature is too much for one question.

That being said heres a cube being translated,scaled,rotated.  The cube has a light source using normals and color:

```js
var gl,
    shaderProgram,
    vertices,
    matrix = mat4.create(),
    vertexCount,
    indexCount,
    q = quat.create(),
    translate =[-3, 0, -10],
    scale = [1,1,1],
    pivot = [0,0,0];
    
    translate2 = [0, 0, -8],
    scale2 = [3,3,3],
    pivot2 = [1,1,1]


initGL();
createShaders();
createVertices();
draw();

function initGL() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
}

function createShaders() {
  var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");
  var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");

  shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);
  gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
}

function createVertices() {
vertices = [
  [-1, -1, -1,     1, 0, 0, 1],     // 0
  [ 1, -1, -1,     1, 1, 0, 1],     // 1
  [-1,  1, -1,     0, 1, 1, 1],     // 2
  [ 1,  1, -1,     0, 0, 1, 1],     // 3
  [-1,  1,  1,     1, 0.5, 0, 1],   // 4
  [1,  1,  1,      0.5, 1, 1, 1],   // 5
  [-1, -1,  1,     1, 0, 0.5, 1],   // 6
  [1, -1,  1,      0.5, 0, 1, 1],   // 7
];

var normals = [
  [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, -1],
  [0, -1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0] ];

var indices = [
  [0, 1, 2,   1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3, 4,   3, 4, 5],
  [4, 5, 6,   5, 6, 7],
  [6, 7, 0,   7, 0, 1],
  [0, 2, 6,   2, 6, 4],
  [1, 3, 7,   3, 7, 5]
];

var attributes = []
for(let side=0; side < indices.length; ++side) {
    for(let vi=0; vi < indices[side].length; ++vi) {
        attributes.push(...vertices[indices[side][vi]]);
        attributes.push(...normals[side]);
    }
}

  vertexCount = attributes.length / 10;

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(attributes), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var coords = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(coords, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 10, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coords); 

  var colorsLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "colors");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorsLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 10, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 3);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorsLocation);

  var normalLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "normal");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(normalLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 10, Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT * 7);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(normalLocation);  
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  
  var lightColor = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightColor");
  gl.uniform3f(lightColor, 1, 1, 1);
  
  var lightDirection = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lightDirection");
  gl.uniform3f(lightDirection, 0.5, 0.5, -1);


  var perspectiveMatrix = mat4.create();
  mat4.perspective(perspectiveMatrix, 1, canvas.width / canvas.height, 0.1, 11);
  var perspectiveLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "perspectiveMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(perspectiveLoc, false, perspectiveMatrix);

}

function draw(timeMs) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  let interval = timeMs / 3000
  let t = interval - Math.floor(interval); 

  let trans_t = vec3.lerp([], translate, translate2, t);
  let scale_t = vec3.lerp([], scale, scale2, t);
  let pivot_t = vec3.lerp([], pivot, pivot2, t);
  let quat_t = quat.slerp(quat.create(), q, [1,0,1,1], t /2);
  mat4.fromRotationTranslationScaleOrigin(matrix, quat_t, trans_t, scale_t, pivot_t);

  var transformMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "transformMatrix");
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrix, false, matrix);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  //gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indexCount, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
}


  /*
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context
   */
  function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript, theSource, currentChild, shader;

    shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!shaderScript) {
      return null;
    }

    theSource = "";
    currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;

    while (currentChild) {
      if (currentChild.nodeType == currentChild.TEXT_NODE) {
        theSource += currentChild.textContent;
      }

      currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
    }
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
      // Unknown shader type
      return null;
    }
    gl.shaderSource(shader, theSource);

// Compile the shader program
    gl.compileShader(shader);

// See if it compiled successfully
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      alert("An error occurred compiling the shaders: " + gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 coords;
uniform mat4 transformMatrix;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec4 colors;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;
varying vec4 varyingColors;
uniform mat4 perspectiveMatrix;
void main(void) {
    vec3 norm = normalize(normal);
    vec3 ld = normalize(lightDirection);
    float dotProduct = max(dot(norm, ld), 0.0);
    vec3 vertexColor = lightColor * colors.rgb * dotProduct;
    varyingColors = vec4(vertexColor, 1);
    gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * transformMatrix  * coords;
}
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 color;
varying vec4 varyingColors;
void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = varyingColors;
}
</script>
```

Comment: the image you show looks more like a post processing effect to me

Comment: @gman I think so too but how is post processing managed when pushing realtime audio though geometry?  what if the music was user generated in realtime too?

Comment: If you just want to distort an image by audio you'd use something like  `float audio = texture2D(audioFrequncyData, vec2(texcoord.y, 0)); vec2 distortedTexcoord = texcoord + vec2(audio, 0); gl_FragColor = texture2D(imageSampler, distortedTexcoord);`

Comment: I don't want to distort an image I would like to distort a piece of 3d geometry. I'll clarify in question above.

Answer (score 1):

I think reasonable way to do it is vertex displacement.
That is adding an offset to vertex position.

To make it work you need to tesselate your cube or take some other mesh with high polygon count. Then you can tie your sine phase to position.

Sort of:

```
float amplitude = 0.1;
vec3 offset = vec3(sin(globalTime + coords.y * 10.0), 0.0, 0.0) * amplitude;
gl_Position = perspectiveMatrix * transformMatrix * (coords + offset);
```

For using audio as input you can [get a spectrum from WebAudio api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) and use some bar value as amplitude. Low frequency value initially works well since that's there kicks sound at. Consider asking api for low detail frequency data (few wide bars).

Also at that point some spectrum filtering might be required to smooth visual effect. For example interpolating spectrum data across few last frames.

Using multiple freq bars as input can result in nice equalizer effect. To make it work you can bake bar index as geometry attribute and displace based on that bar value.

Comment: I know this is nooby question but `vec3 offset = vec3(sin(globalTime + coords.y * 10.0), 0.0, 0.0) * amplitude; ` break the shader? If I remove `globalTime + coords.y` the shader starts working again. Could you add your snippet to my script in the question for your answer?

Comment: You need to pass globalTime variable as uniform to use it in shader. Add `uniform float globalTime;` and on js side `var globalTimeU = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "globalTime"); gl.uniform1f(globalTimeU , myJSTimeVariable);`.